# Does موجود is a Modern Standard Arabic word?

Tags: historical-linguistics, arabic

Does موجود is a Modern Standard Arabic word which is originated from وَجَدَ after the revelation of Quran because موجود is not mentioned anywhere in Quran?

Comment: Haven't we seen this word just a short time ago? https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/43548/can-you-please-tell-me-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%ac%d9%88%d8%af-is-the-word-of-which-language

Answer (score 1):

It is a word in both modern standard Arabic and classical Arabic. Just because it was not mentioned in the Qur'án does not mean it is not a word. The Qur'án is not a dictionary, and it does not have every word in the Arabic language. Further proof of it being a word is the fact that other words of the same root are indeed found in the Qur'án, it is just that this specific word isn't.

Comment: But i have a link where it says that موجود is a Modern Standard Arabic word not classical!

Comment: @BilalKhan I would like to see this link, because having studied both, I know that it is was indeed a word in classical Arabic.

Comment: http://www.lisaanmasry.org/online/word.php?id=23129

Comment: @BilalKhan, the website does not say that the word is not in classical Arabic, it just doesn't include classical Arabic, likely because it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bilal -- The term “classical” is a bit ambiguous.  The Arabic term is *fuṣḥā*, which is routinely applied to MSA as well as the “heritage” language, since MSA purports to follow the rules of classical Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

mawjūd is the passive participle of the verb wajada “to find”, so its literal meaning is “having been found”. As a participle it is common in classical Arabic, but as far as I can see, in the meaning “existing” it is modern, or in case not common in the classical language. It might help if you could direct us to the mentioned link.